# Combile retrieve query laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have 3 query like this

```
first Photos::where('approve',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(2)->get();
second Photos::where('approve',1)->orderBy('created_at','asc')->take(2)->get();
last Photos::where('approve',0)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(2)->get();
```

how i join this into one query.. in implementation i want to create news online which have many feature so i want try to create many query but some of my friend said that maximun query to get high peformance is 4 query / page

Answer (score 0):

These seem to be small queries enough so that you do not need to join into one. There are literally pages that do tens of hundreds of queries.

Each of these should take only milliseconds so I recommend you to start optimizing only if there are real problems detected.